# Setup and Deployment does not want to uninstall older version and install new version

Tags: setup-project

I have a wpf application written in framework 4. The application is downloaded via a file share and installed on the user pc - an icon will appear on the desktop and the user can click on icon to use the application.

However I used the standard setup and deployment project found in VS 2010 to create an installer program, I have also set the "RemovePreviousVersions = True" on the setup and deployment project properties.

However when I do any change on the application, deploy application and then add NEW deployment files to setup and deployment project, and build the S&D project and run the new setup.exe it DOES pick up that a previous version is installed but does not remove it, just gives me an error that install cannot continue becuase of older version.

WHat could I be doing wrong?

Kind Regards
_geoNeo

Comment: Hi all i eventually found a solution thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else is wondering, the solution is to increase the ProductVersion and answer Yes when prompted about changing the ProductCode.